# Laravel 5.5 find($id) returns collection instead of single object

Tags: laravel

Laravel 5.5 find($id) returns collection instead of single object

Any idea why, and how to prevent this? I'm having to use `->first()` as workaround

```
public function destroy(client $client)
    {

        $item = Client::findOrFail($client)->first();
        $item->delete();

        session()->flash('message', 'Client deleted');

        return redirect('/clients');

    }
```

Comment: please print your whole query where you use `find()`. Is there only one result in your collection?

Comment: yes, only one result. Question updated with relevant code.

Comment: It shouldn’t. So are you overloading Eloquent methods somewhere?

Comment: `find` should only return one model. I would think the problem is somewhere else, for instance why are you type hinting something that isn't a class name? You should look in to route model binding.

Comment: I’d also be more attentive to your formatting. In your type-hint `client` is all-lowercase, yet if it’s a class it should be “StudlyCase” (i.e. `Client`).

Comment: Auto generated through `php artisan make:model client -mcr` should I have used StudlyCase for that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`find()` and `findOrFail()` need an integer to return one element. If you pass something else, you will get a collection.

Since you are asking for a `Client` object as a parameter, you don't have to check it. Laravel will never fire this function when the object does not exists, so you don't have to check it.

```
public function destroy(Client $client)
{

    $client->delete();

    session()->flash('message', 'Client deleted');

    return redirect('/clients');

}
```

For more information read https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models and the following part with `not found exception`

Comment: I created the controller using `php artisan make:model -mcr` - didn't know it did this amount of magic! Thanks for your input

Comment: "If you pass something else, you will get a collection." That was helpful for me. I THOUGHT I was passing an integer, but upon double-checking, you were right.

Comment: I'm with Ryan on this one, just ran into this today and had no idea that what I was passing in was NOT the id!

Answer (score 1):

`$client` is already an instance of `Client` as you typehint it. You shouldn't need to "find" it again. Checking if it exists and then run `delete` should be enough.

```
public function destroy(client $client)
{

    if ($client->exists)
        $client->delete();

    session()->flash('message', 'Client deleted');

    return redirect('/clients');

}
```

Comment: you don't need to check if it exists, because if it does not the function will never be called. Laravel will throw a notfound-exception.